# run jquery on php page open

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery notification bar script that im using. I don't know the first thing about jquery and javascript, but anyway, heres the code:

```
<script src="jquery.bar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $("#msgup").bar({
        color  : '#FFFFFF',
        background_color : '#8F0000',
        removebutton : false,
        message : 'hello',
        time : 4000
    });
```

how do i run this using php echo when the page opens? To run it with a link i use this

```
<a id=bar>click here</a>
```

this code would run in a section of the page that refreshes every 10 sections using jquery, so yeah, must check on 'page load'

Comment: Can you give us a little more info? Do you just want the bar to appear on page load?

Comment: And what do you want it to do? The script runs on page load, but it runs the 'bar' addin on an element with id 'msgup'. I don't know what 'bar' does, not what the link has to do with it. You should check the documentation for that plugin.  If you just want to show a bar, you don't need JQuery at all, you can just build the HTML for it.

Comment: there isnt much documentation http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/ im guessing it assumes the user knows the basics, which i dont

Comment: i just need to know how to run it

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your code goes here
});
```

This will get run when the page opens

Comment: ah man i give up. they make these scripts for alerts to pop up, not when a user clicks a CLICK ME link, yet i just cannot figure it and its been frustrating me for days. thanks anyway

Comment: If you want to run JavaScript code when a user picks a button or link, use the onclick event - <button onclick=" // your code goes here or call a javascript function">CLICK ME</button>